# Spring Boot doesn't use CommonsMultipartResolver?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have a problem with REST web service running with Spring Boot (Jetty).
One of my REST method is file upload and I'm guessing that CommonsMultipartResolver is not using during multipart requests.

Signature of this upload method is :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public BaseResponse upload(@RequestParam("login") String login, @RequestParam("passwd") String passwd,
        @RequestParam("partner") String partner, @RequestParam("fileName") String fName, 
        @RequestParam("length") int fLen, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException
```

I also have a root application class like below :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BootApplication {

    private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(BootApplication.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(BootApplication.class,
                new ClassPathResource("WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"),
                new ClassPathResource("WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml"));
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(ServletContext servletContext) {
        _logger.log(Level.INFO, "[BootApplication] Fetching CommonsMultipartResolver");
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver(servletContext);
    }
}
```

When I'm calling this method I got an error :

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:253)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What's strange in this stack trace I cannot see any `CommonsMultipartResolver` calls. 
Another thing is that exactly the same code was working in GlassFish environment - I could upload files with no problem. What changed is that `multipartResolver` bean in GlassFish was defined in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and in Spring Boot I initialize it in `BootApplication` class. I also tried to left `multipartResolver` in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` which I'm also loading for configuration but none of this solution worked.

When I'm looking at `/beans` endpoint in Spring Boot I can see `multipartResolver` bean. No other bean has dependency to this `multipartResolver` bean - maybe this is wrong, but I have no idea how to configure it properly.

Below you have my `dispatcher-servlet.xml` if it will help :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot then use it, you are trying to work around it.

Spring Boot by default already configures file uploading so you can remove your definition. If you want to control certain values you can configure those by adding properties to the `application.properties`. See [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration) of the reference guide.

I would suggest removing your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` because Spring Boot already enables MVC configuration and you enabling it interferes with the auto configuration. Assuming that your `BootApplication` is inside the `com.my.package` you can already remove the file as it adds nothing, if the `BootApplication` is in a different package add `@ComponentScan("com.my.package")` to the configuration.

To import the `applicationContext.xml` add a `@ImportResource` to your `BootApplication` instead of what you are doing now. However depending on what is in there (probably some datasource, JPA, etc. configuration you might even remove it and replace it with some simple properties instead).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
@ImportResource("WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
public class BootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The main problem is is that you are disabling part of the Spring Boot auto configuration to properly let it configure things.

Comment: Thank you very much ! With your solution my upload method is now working ! :) I've used dispatcher-servlet.xml file beacuse I was using it when I was deploying my application to Glassfish, but now I see that is really unnecessary.

Comment: I would also guess the same applies to the `applicationContext.xml` you might want to clean that up also and use the auto config features of Spring Boot.

Comment: I also moved configuration from `applicationContext.xml` to configuration classes and everything work well. Now I'm free from XML configuration. Thanks for advice !

Comment: How to restrict the user to upload only csv file using CommonsMultipartResolver using java configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

I think they have resolved the issue in Spring-Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipart = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipart.setMaxUploadSize(3 * 1024 * 1024);
    return multipart;
}

@Bean
@Order(0)
public MultipartFilter multipartFilter() {
    MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
    return multipartFilter;
}
```

You also need to exclude Spring-Boot's MulipartAutoConfiguration.class

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})

This worked for me.

Comment: How to restrict the user to upload only csv file using CommonsMultipartResolver using java configuration ?